# Microsoft Graph API Update Range Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, httpclient

I'm trying to update excel file from microsoft graph api using JAVA 19.

I tried using JAVA sdk graph APi client v5.0.0 to execute equivalent of:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{sheet-id}/range(address='A1:B2') Content-type: application/json

{ "values" : [["Hello", "100"],["1/1/2016", null]], "formulas" : [[null, null], [null, "=B1*2"]], "numberFormat" : [[null,null], ["m-ddd", null]] }
```

But I was unable to find the good patch() method to do so. I only try the following examples:

```
var valueOfA1 = _graphApiClient
             .drives(DRIVE_ID)
             .items(ITEM_ID)
             .workbook()
             .worksheets("Sheet1")
             .range(WorkbookWorksheetRangeParameterSet.newBuilder()
                     .withAddress("A1")
                     .build())
             .buildRequest()
             .get();
```

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/1063

```
WorkbookRangeFill workbookRangeFill = new WorkbookRangeFill(); workbookRangeFill.color = "#00FF00";

graphClient.me().drive().items("{id}").workbook().worksheets("sheet1")
    .range(WorkbookWorksheetRangeParameterSet
        .newBuilder()
        .withAddress("$B$1")
        .build()).format().fill()
    .buildRequest()
    .patch(workbookRangeFill);
```

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/744
But seems there is an issue with address.

Then try by Http client:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(); 
HttpPatch httpPatch = new HttpPatch("http://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/workbook/worksheets/{name}/range(address='F10:F12')"); 
httpPatch.addHeader("Authorization", accessToken); 
httpPatch.setEntity(new StringEntity("{\"values\":[[\"Hello\"],[\"How\"],[\"Are You?\"]]}", "application/json", "UTF-8")); 
HttpEntity responseEntity = httpClient.execute(httpPatch).getEntity(); 
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
```

Resulting in nothing, no error and no content returned and no update range. Does anyone got a working http request ?